# Flutter keyboard gif support

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I'm looking for a way to receive gifs from keyboards in Flutter. When I try to select a gif I get the following message in my application:

> Appname doesn't support image insertion here

Comment: Seems like there is an open [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2022) regarding the missing support for this function.

Comment: Did you found a solution for it?

Comment: @FilipeOS No - not yet

Comment: Did you guys ever find a solution? I read somewhere that I can get what the input is from the keyboard and display it how I want but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: No; my solution was to go native.

Answer (score 1):

It is now supported since jan 2023.
In TextField or TextFormField, add this:

```
                 onContentInserted: (KeyboardInsertedContent data) async {
                    if (data.data != null) {
                      //Do something with the data
                    }
                  },
```

For more information, check this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/contentInsertionConfiguration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Inserting image and GIF using phones built-in keyboard is not yet supported in Flutter. In fact, there is an [open GitHub ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67857) regarding this issue.

To summarize, Flutter's `TextField`, `TextFormField` or any text input boxes do not accept characters other than the ones specified in [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/).

But according to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30688#issuecomment-519716702), you may explore using [extended_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field). It provides a widget named [SpecialText](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field#special-text) and [ImageSpan](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field#imagespan) widget which could be use to add images in the text field (including GIFs).